# How to divide a number with dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I'm stumped. I want to divide the length of a list by the number values in a dictionary.

```
firstNum = 96
secondNum = 97

list = [1,2,3,4]
dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

for x in range(0,13):
firstNum += 1
secondNum += 1

    for i in range(firstNum, secondNum):
        percent = len(list) / dictionary.get(chr(i))
        print(percent)
```

But I get the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

As I understand it, the .get function returns the value, which should be an int? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @idjaw But won't that return that value for a & b?

Comment: I didn't write what I said properly. Using `chr` you have to use the appropriate code from the ascii table. If you wanted to get `a`, you actually have to call `chr(97)`. What I meant to say is that your utilization is incorrect. Look at the ascii table here: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. Do you want to diving the `len` of your list with every number in the dictionary ? i.e. `len(list)/1` then `len(list)/2` and so on ?

Comment: Furthermore, there is certainly a much easier way to do what you are doing. Can you please add more detail to what you are trying to do? What is the significane of firstNum and secondNum, why are you doing two loops. What is the first loop resonsible for? You mentioned you wanted to divide the length of the list over each value of the dictionary. But that seems to be just a part of your overall code.

Comment: @idjaw Thankyou for your help about how to use chr and ascii tables. My original question has been answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going solely by the title - Diving the list by the values in your dictionary

all you need is :

```
>>> l= [1,2,3,4]
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for i in d.values():
...     print len(l)/i
...
4
2
>>>
```

`dictionary.values()` gives you all the values in your dictionary as a list